# NextJS localstorage is not defined

Tags: redux, next.js, local-storage

How can i fix this? i'm trying to almacenate my cartItems state in the localStorage but nextJs throw me localstorage is not defined error.

```
const initialState = {
  cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
    : [],
  cartTotalQuantity: 0,
  cartTotalAmout: 0,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is defined only in browsers (of course!)

in `Next.js`, your code is run both in the `browser` and the `server`.

You can safely initialize and use your state in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook like this

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState({ cartItems: [], cartTotalQuantity: 0, cartTotalAmount: 0 });

  // This code runs after the component mounted
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const cartItemsString = localStorage.get('cartItems');

    if (cartItemsString) {
      setMyState((prev) => ({ ...prev, cartItems: JSON.parse(cartItemsString) }))
    }
  }, [])

  return <>YOUR JSX GOES HERE</>
}
```

Comment: but we're not allowed to write useEffect hook inside of a redux store, how can we do that then?